# How can I clone a Github repo to an Amazon EC2 instance running apache2

Tags: apache, github, amazon-ec2, ssh

I seem to be having some issues with SSH and Github on my EC2 instance. I am trying to clone a Github repo and am having permission errors, but when checking my SSH connection it seems to be fine. I have tried deleting and adding the key to Github amongst other things. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[Result from checking github SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRnBv.png)

[Result from attempting to clone Github repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycZML.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please insert console output within your post, e.g. in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the clone you're using `sudo` which means that your ~/.ssh is different (`/root/.ssh` vs `/home/ubuntu/.ssh`) from the first command.  I'm guessing that you're doing this so you have permission to write into `/var/www`.

If you need to write to this directory one was is to change the permission in it (i.e. `sudo chmod 777 /var/www`).  However, I'd really advise against this as you don't want a bug to allow anyone to write into this directory.

The other way is to checkout the code to a local directory (i.e. `/home/ubuntu/www`) and then move the files there with sudo (i.e. `sudo mv /home/ubuntu/www/* /var/www`).

Comment: Thanks, neither one of those seemed to work though. I tried the first one as the project is more practice than anything and got the same result. I am not sure I fully understand the second solution and struggle to find the local directory of /home/ubuntu/var or /home/ubuntu/www

Comment: If you were to, for example, run `mkdir www`, `cd www`, your git clone, `cd webServicesIndex` and then `sudo mv * /var/www` you would have created a temporary directory, cloned into it, and moved everything from that clone into `/var/www`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use ssh method to clone a repository. To clone a repository using the ssh method you need to complete verification. You can skip all the hassle and can directly clone the repository using the repository link. Try using the command

```
git clone https://github.com/JSutliff/webServicesIndex html
```

and the repository will be cloned in the folder named html without any verification.